# having issues with sip api support

Tags: android, sip, voip, android-2.3-gingerbread

i am creating sip application. i am testing it on my micromax a26 and it has android 2.3.5 and i am having problems

**-->1**

when i am executing this code

```
if(SipManager.isApiSupported(getApplicationContext()))
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "support", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not support", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

i am getting "not support" alert.

in this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html it says i need You must have a mobile device that is running Android 2.3 or higher.

what i am missing???

**-->2**

at this line

```
if(manager == null) {
         manager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
       }

if (manager == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "manager null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
```

i am again getting alert "manager null" so i can guess that SipManager.newInstance(this) is retuning null.  see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html#newInstance%28android.content.Context%29

this is my whole code

```
package com.archish;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.net.sip.*;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;


import java.text.ParseException;

public class SipTestActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener{

public String sipAddress;

public static SipManager manager = null;
public SipProfile me = null;
public SipAudioCall call =null;
//public IncomingCallReceiver callReceiver;
EditText Domain;
EditText UId;
EditText Pwd;


private static final int CALL_ADDRESS = 1;
private static final int SET_AUTH_INFO = 2;
private static final int UPDATE_SETTINGS_DIALOG = 3;
private static final int HANG_UP = 4;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Domain=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtDomain);
    UId=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtUid);
    Pwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPwd);

    if(SipManager.isApiSupported(getApplicationContext()))
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "support", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not support", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.archish.INCOMING_CALL");  

    initializeManager();

    /*Button Reg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnReg);
    Reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on click ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                Register();
            } catch (SipException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });*/
}
private void initializeManager()  {
     if(manager == null) {
         manager = SipManager.newInstance(getBaseContext());
       }
     Register();
}
public void Register() 
{

    if (manager == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "manager null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (me != null) {
        closeLocalProfile();
    }

    try{
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder("1001", "123");
        builder.setPassword("1234");
        me = builder.build();


        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("com.archish.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);          
        manager.open(me, pi, null);

        // This listener must be added AFTER manager.open is called,
        // Otherwise the methods aren't guaranteed to fire.

        manager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {
                public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registering with SIP Server...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   // updateStatus("Registering with SIP Server...");
                }

                public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "reaDy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   // updateStatus("Ready");
                }

                public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                        String errorMessage) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration failed.  Please check settings.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   // updateStatus("Registration failed.  Please check settings.");
                }
            });
    }
    catch (ParseException pe) {
        //updateStatus("Connection Error.");
    } catch (SipException se) {
        //updateStatus("Connection error.");
    }


}
private void closeLocalProfile() {
    if (manager == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (me != null) {
            manager.close(me.getUriString());
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        Log.d("WalkieTalkieActivity/onDestroy", "Failed to close local profile.", ee);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

please help me !!! i am new in android, give me any hint to solve this... what is the problem????